# add class is not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, addclass

I have **header contents** which are listed out in separate file. I will call it in each Html page by `[<span id="header_contents"]`.

In these Header I need to show active links,where the user stays in this page.

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
           <li>
               <a href="index.html"><span id="homePage" class="active">
                       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span>&nbsp;
                        HOME</span>
               </a>
           </li>
           ..
           ..
       </ul>
  </div>
```

Given below is my Js

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
           // Set BaseURL
     var baseURL = 'file:///home/arun/Taxi-New/taxi-web/webapp/';

      // Get current URL and replace baseURL
     var href = window.location.href.replace(baseURL, '');

     // Remove trailing slash
    href = href.substr(-1) == '/' ? href.substr(0, href.length - 1) : href;

     // Get last part of current URL
    var page = href.substr(href.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

          if(page == 'index.html'){
          $( '#homePage' ).addClass( 'active' );          
        }else{
          $('#homePage').removeClass('active');
        }
       });
```

Css

```
.active{
    border-bottom: 3px solid #3498db;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use as, You are missing `=` in `if` condition

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
  ..
  if(page == 'index.html'){
     $( '#homePage').addClass( 'active' );          
   }else{
     $('#homePage').removeClass('active');
  }
 });
```

Comment: Just wanted to post this.

Comment: @Downvoter please have little courtesy to give reason for downvote so person who gives answer will improve his answer or maybe you wanted to  reduce reputations of other users

Comment: The answer of user who don't have downvotes may be culprit :)

Comment: ah ..I am sorry Guys .I have missed [==] this while updating the code

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie I was not pointing to you. Hahaha. But this case is of serial downvotes. Its not you but someone.

Comment: @Shoaib Chikate: Apparently the question had a typo ()now fixed) and that was not the problem after all... I think we should wait for more information about `page`.

Comment: @arunsmartarrow You forget to use == but don't forget to accept answer of the person who gave appropriate and efficient answer.

Comment: i apologize for Missing my comparison operator(==).But Fix has not been solved

Answer (score 1):

Based on the additional comments I can now guess you used `window.location` and expected that to be a string. It is actually an object so `substr` resulted in a error. You needed:

```
 var href = window.location.href;
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/h1sm69sb/2/

The clue is in your comment about using `window.location` as that will be a full URL so will not match. You need to do a substring match instead. e.g. using `indexOf()`

You are also better off using `toggleClass` with a Boolean switch value:

http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  ..
     $( '#homePage').toggleClass('active', page.indexOf('index.html') >= 0);
});
```

This will add the class if the switch value is true or remove it when false.

Answer (score -1):

You forgot the double '==' in the if statement

if(page == 'index.html'){

Answer (score -1):

Here you are using = assignment operator which will never compare page with "index.html" instead it will make the current value of page as index.html

Change = to ==:

```
if(page=="index.html"){

}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //...
    if(page === 'index.html'){
        $( '#homePage' ).addClass( 'active' );          
    }else{
        $('#homePage').removeClass('active');
    }
});
```

You are compare the variable p and string "index.html",so you should use identifier "===" but not "=",hope can help you~